# Datasource filtering on databound controls

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource, bindingsource

I have this form on an application that I created the controls (textboxes) by dragging and dropping an employeemaster datasource onto the the form.

[image]

For now, the form works for all my needs for handling employees.

I have created a new field (business name) in my employeemaster table that I want to store the particular business associated with an employee.
I now want to set a condition such that the form only loads with employees of a particular business set as a variable.

How do I filter the employee BindingSource to achieve this?
Do I have to individually bind each control with a filter through code?
I have not found much help on the internet.

Comment: What is your datasource's datasource? (a DataTable?)

Comment: Its a dataset created in VS. Add New Item -> Data -> DataSet configured from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data you'll have in your database, you can do 1 of the following;

Either you filter on the datasource:

```
bsEmployee.DataSource.Filter = "AcolumnName like 'value'";
```

or you will make a sql query and add that to your TableAdapter, so that you will not load too much data into your application. (To add a parameterzied query go to DataSet designer,right click the TableAdapter you want to modify, and add a query. in the where statement you can write something like this " WHERE (columnName = @VariableName)"

```
taEmployee.FillByDepartment(datasetName.dataTableName, departmentNameVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The second options seems better. If I add WHERE        (businessName LIKE @businessName) to the statement in my dataset designer, how will I map this new variable to the business name variable in my code?

Comment: Are you asking how to call upon a query in the TableAdapter, or how to bind and add a new field to your form?

Comment: I am setting each user that logs on to the application with a different business. All employees are saved on the same table. I have a variable that holds the businessname (session) on app run. I was asking how do I set the where statement parameter to take up this businessname session. Not sure if my English is clear enough.

Comment: Thats exacly what I needed. Changed it to taEmployee.FillBy(datasetName.dataTableName, departmentNameVariable);